# How do I access the next page on quotes.toscrape.com?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the next page of quotes.toscrape.com with python BeautifulSoup. Preferably I want to be able to scrape the next page and the next etc.

I have tried asking chatGPT and the replit ai, however I keep getting errors that they and I can't fix. I think it's because the href of the button doesn't have a full URL but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the URL structure for a specific page is simply `https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/<PAGENUMBER>/`. So just do something like this:

```py
import requests
import bs4

pagenumber = 1
while True:
    print("Getting page ", pagenumber)
    url = f'{https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{pagenumber}/'
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    # ...scrape things here...
    pagenumber += 1
```

Or create pagenumber iterator:

```py
import bs4
import requests
from itertools import count

pagenumbers = count(start=1)
for pagenumber in pagenumbers:
    print("Getting page ", pagenumber)
    url = f'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{pagenumber}/'
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
    # ...scrape things here...
```